# Is there a way to make a string from ArrayList elements?

Tags: java

I want to ask the user for a message:

> "Enter a message in the following format: "TO FROM MESSAGE : KEY"

Example input from user:

> 1 2 hey there how are you : bubble123

Then, I want to have the `SecureMessage` class return the message. However, I do not know how to create a String of the message part, as the `getMessage()` *message* requires a String assigned to it.

The `SecureMessage` class should not have any mutators in it. All fields in `SecureMessage` are set from the `Message` class.

```
public class SecureMessage {
    
    private String message;
    private String sourceName;
    private String destName;
    private String key;
    
    public SecureMessage(String message, String sourceName, String destName, String key){
        this.message = message;
        this.sourceName = sourceName;
        this.destName = destName;
        this.key = key;
    }
    
    public String getMessage(String key){ 
        return message + " from SecureMessage class";
    }
    
    public String getSourceName(){
        return sourceName + " from SecureMessage class";
    }
    
    public String getDestName(){
        return destName + " from SecureMessage class";
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Message {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String message = "blank", sourceName = "blank", destName = "blank", key = "blank", messageInput, userMessageDetails;
        ArrayList<String> messageInputList = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Enter message in form TO FROM MESSAGE : KEY \nExample --- 1 2 hey there how are you? : bubble123");
        userMessageDetails = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        String str = userMessageDetails;
        String[] tokens = str.split(" ");        
        for(String s : tokens){
            messageInputList.add(s);
        }
        
        System.out.println(messageInputList);
        System.out.println("");
        int x = messageInputList.size();
        
        destName = messageInputList.get(0);
        sourceName = messageInputList.get(1);
        key = messageInputList.get(x-1);
//--this is where I am lost, because I need to pass a string to the SecureMessage getMessage() method---
//        message = ???;
// I found out how to print the items, however this is not a string...
//        for(int i = 2; i <= (x-3); i++){
//            System.out.print(messageInputList.get(i) + " ");
//        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        
        SecureMessage secMsg = new SecureMessage(message, sourceName, destName, key);
        System.out.println(secMsg.getDestName());
        System.out.println(secMsg.getSourceName());
        System.out.println(secMsg.getMessage(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for what I see, as you split by " ", then you will have your message split between messageInputList.get(2) and messageInputList.get(x-3).
The easy way is having a for and concatenate strings. Something like:

```
String s_message = "";

for(int i = 2; i <= (x-3); i++){
    s_message = s_message + messageInputList.get(i) + " ";
}
```

Comment: It of course makes no real difference here speed-wise, since the list is so small, but it's bad form to use String addition in an iteration loop.  Better to use a StringBuffer or StringBuilder.

Comment: Thank you so much Carles! Such a simple thing to do but it is exactly what I needed!

Comment: My pleasure to help pleigh05! :)

Comment: Yes Steve, for performance is better StringBuffer or StringBuilder as joining the string will create a new string with the addition one time and another and another... but I saw he was stuck and he just needed a very simple solution. To get a real impact this code would had to run with very large messages or many instances and if it was the case it would not use split in the first case, also for performance, that would require a better protocol. Just kept it simple. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
message = String.join(" ", messageInputList.subList(2, x-2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! While I can see that this seems to be a better form than the answer I chose that solved my issue, I believe this is unfortunately too complex for what I am being asked to do, as we have not covered this kind of material. I will refer to your answer in the future as it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
message = IntStream.range(2, x - 2)
    .mapToObj(messageInputList::get)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

This will collect the elements from your `messageInputList` from index 2 to x-2 and collect them to a singular String `message` which you can pass to your `SecureMessage` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be much more simplier:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter message data.");
    System.out.println("-------------------");

    System.out.print("Destination name: ");
    String destName = scan.next();

    System.out.print("Source name: ");
    String sourceName = scan.next();

    System.out.print("Key: ");
    String key = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Message (multi-line, double ENTER to finish):");
    scan.useDelimiter("\n\n\n");
    String message = scan.next().trim();

    SecureMessage secMsg = new SecureMessage(message, sourceName, destName, key);
    System.out.println(secMsg.getDestName());
    System.out.println(secMsg.getSourceName());
    System.out.println(secMsg.getMessage(key));
}
```